# Динамическое формирование фонового изображения

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, изображения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что будет лучшим способом решения следующей задачи: из изображения 1 скопировать область шириной в 1 пиксель и полной высотой (справа или слева), затем полученным изображением путем повторения по оси x замостить фон контейнера 2. На ум приходят два варианта — `canvas` из 1 и `new Image()`, либо динамическое формирование ссылки на стороне сервера (лишний запрос).
Есть ли варианты более изящного кросбраузерного решения, либо описанные способы являются оптимальными?

Comment: Мне очень интересно, как вы будете решать такую задачу через `new Image()`? Можете поделиться примером кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что значит "динамическое формирование"?

Если вам нужно фоновое изображение сделать таким, чтобы казалось будто первый столбец пикселов растянут на всю ширину, то самое простое решение вот:

```
.image {
    background-size: 1000000000% 100%;
    image-rendering: pixelated; /*Chrome*/
    image-rendering: optimizespeed; /*FF*/
}
```

растяжение фоновой картинки по горизонтали в миллионы раз даст то что надо даже на 4к дисплее.

Comment: Динамические означает формирующееся динамически, во время выполнения скрипта. Интересный вариант, спасибо

Comment: Действительно интересный вариант. А как с поддержкой браузеров? Можете добавить сниппет?

Comment: Зачем сниппет? `background-size` поддерживают все браузеры (у ИЕ ограничение - максимум 1000000000%). А image-rendering нужен для того, чтобы линии были резкими. Более развернутый пример этого свойства тут: https://codepen.io/tombennet/pen/wBNxvQ

Кстати, мой ИЕ11, похоже, чихать на -ms-interpolation-mode хотел.

Answer (score 2):

В принципе другого подхода может и не быть.

Вот вариант с `canvas`.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 1;
canvas.height = 281;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  div.style.background = 'url("' + dataURL + '")';
}
// Тут проблема с CORS была, поэтому пришлось в base64 картинку преобразовать
img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Да, именно такой вариант я и имел ввиду. Вариант выше выглядит необычно, но вполне работоспособная нативная функция